# How to compute time complexity of this implementation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
 boolean isUnique(String s){
        char [] temp = s.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < temp.length; j++){
                if(temp[i] == temp[j]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

this is just to check if all characters in the string is unique. 
I learn from other examples that, with inner loop its usually O(n^2) but in this case the inner loop doesnt start from index 0. It starts from the next element whatever `temp[i]` is. So i'm a bit confuse how to determine the time complexity.

Comment: the  inner loop will run following times in worst case:
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3).......+(1) where n is the length of string. so when you will sum this sequence. The highest order will be n^2. So the worst time complexity became O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good notational explanation for this
Assume both loops started from `0` to say `8` your `temp.length`, then visualize it this way

```
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O
```

So count the number of `o`'s here, they sum up to be `o(n^2)`

Now coming to your situation
The outer loop starts from `0` and the inner loop continues from that till the end each time, so

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 // 0+7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0   // 1+6
0 0 0 0 0 0    //2+5
0 0 0 0 0      //3+4
0 0 0 0       //4+3
0 0 0        // 5+2
0 0          //6+1
0            //7+0
```

Count the number of `0`'s here, they are `(n^2)/2`, which is `o(n^2)` itself

The first column represents the outer loop and the after that, represents number of iterations of the inner loop

Explanation `//First loop count + second loop iterations`

Answer (score 2):

The number of comparisons in the first iteration of the outer loop is `n`. In the second it is `n-1`, and so on down to 0. So we have a sum:

```
n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1
```

which is equal to

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

which is

```
(n^2 + n) * 1/2
```

as `1/2` is just constant and `n^2` grows faster than `n` we consider the complexity to by `O(n^2)`.